# Суперпозиция, не получается решить задачу

Tags: дискретная-математика, булева-алгебра

Дана функция, нужно из заданного набора других трёх функций с помощью отождествлений и подстановок следующую суперпозицию https://ibb.co/cXY6n9d .
На лекциях разбор был с простыми функциями, применяя те же действия, у меня получается либо сборная солянка из кучи переменных, либо что-то, что невозможно упростить, может здесь нужно действовать как-то иначе?

Comment: Использую то, что сказано в задаче - подставляю функции в аргументы и пытаюсь по возможности упростить, но ни к чему, похожему на ответ, это не приводит

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.